# Where can I find/buy/steal a good bow at low levels?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am role-playing a level 6 female Redguard focused on Archery and Sneak, with Light Armor, One-Handed and Alchemy as support skills. I used to get good bows in TES: Morrowind and TES: Oblivion at low levels, so where can I find, buy or steal a good bow in TES: Skyrim?

Buy good I mean a bow that inflicts high damage, regardless the material of the bow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO, the best way to get a great bow at such a low level is to just max out your smithing level and make a daedric one. It will probably be a struggle for you to get all the materials needed to do so, unless you use a mod. But from what I remember, there isnt really another way to get a good bow.

Comment: Honestly at such a low level, the strength of a bow wont matter much. At level 6 an Ancient Nord Bow, or an Imperial Bow will serve you fine. As you go up levels the likelihood of you finding a better bow will increase, it wont be long until you fine an Orcish, Dwarven, or Elf bow... As for unique bows you can always google their location, most can be found along specific quest lines or in specific dungeons. [This is a good resource.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bows_(Skyrim))

Comment: What about Nightingale's Bow? Wouldn't be a good choice?

Comment: But you can't just steal that at a low level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most loot in Skyrim is level dependent to a degree - enemies/chests will not start carrying ebony gear until around lvl 36, for example.

Some of the sought after unique gear like [Nightingale Bow](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_Bow) will have different stats depending on when you obtain them. Enchantment aside, the base stats on the Nightingale Bow at minimum level are roughly equivalent to that of a Forsworn bow. And the forsworn are all around The Reach so you can probably grab one of their bows fairly easily.

Looking over [The Elder Scrolls Wiki's entry on bows](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bows_(Skyrim)), there's a few areas where you might be able to grab an [Elven Bow](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elven_Bow_(Skyrim)) at low levels, and [Glass Bows](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Bow_(Skyrim)) *might* have a low chance to spawn in boss chests even at level 6.

There is also supposed to be a guaranteed [Ebony Bow](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Bow_(Skyrim)) in [Lost Valkygg](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Valkygg), but be warned that this can be exceptionally difficult for low-level players as there are enemies that do not normally spawn until much higher levels.

Alternatively; if your role-playing allows; if you get conjuration to 50, you can use a [Bound Bow](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bound_Bow_(Skyrim)) which temporarily gives you an ethereal Daedric Bow/Arrows.

Comment: Bound bow is going to be pretty good.  Level conjuration by casting Soul Trap on a dead body and you'll get to 50 in no time.

Comment: I'll search in those places you mentioned, besides I could give a try in Lost Valkygg going with Lydia jejeje.

Answer (score 2):

Forsworn bows is the best bet at a low level. i used it until i got the Nightingale's bow. or you can steal a dwarven bow right off the back from Lod's home in Falkreath. i'v found one in his chest every time without fail.

Comment: Really? I think I'll pay a visit to Lod's, my Sneak and Pickpocket skills are really high now

Comment: also Aela the Huntress at Jorrvaskr has an elven bow in display

Answer (score -2):

You can use the hidden dawnstar chest. I've gotten 2 fire enchanted bows and one frost enchanted

Comment: Loot in Skyrim is randomized.

Comment: I know, but you can still get good weapons of nearly any kind in the chest